# Linear Algebra. What is a line, plane, and $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am curious what these three are, easy way to figure out which is which (is it a plane, line, or $\mathbb{R}^3$), and an example of each. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, a line is a one dimensional space, so we choose a point $a=(1,2,3)$ and a direction $v=(1,1,1)$ then the line through that point is the set $\{a+\lambda v | \lambda \in \mathbb{R} \} = \{ (1+\lambda,2+\lambda,3+\lambda) \}$.

A plane is a two dimensional space, so we need two different directions so if we take $w=(0,0,1)$ then we get $\{a+\lambda v + \mu w \} = \{ (1+\lambda,2+\lambda,3+\lambda+\mu) \}$.

$\mathbb{R}^3$ is just three dimensional so we need a third direction $x=(1,1,0)$ (this should be chosen so we get "new" points) and we get  $\{a+\lambda v + \mu w + \alpha x \} = \{ (1+\lambda+\alpha,2+\lambda+\alpha,3+\lambda+\mu) \}$.

In order for these to be vector spaces, we require them to contain the origin $(0,0,0)$ which is easily done by choosing $a$ to be that at the start.

Hopefully you can see how this construction would work should we want to get a line or plane in $4$-dimensional space as well.